# Error creating bean with name: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, spring

I cant figure it out whats the problem, to me it seems that i have already taken all the necessary steps, simple testing program and it wont work, to me without any reason.

---

```
@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentServiceInterface studentService;

    @PostMapping("/student")
    public Student save(@RequestBody Student student){
        return studentService.saveStudent(student);
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface StudentServiceInterface {
    Student saveStudent(Student student);
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentServiceInterface{

    @Autowired
    StudentRepositoryInterface studentRepository;

    @Override
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Integer age;
    ...
}
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eHFY.png)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentService': Error creating bean with name 'studentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentRepository': Error creating bean with name 'studentRepositoryInterface' defined in com.example.springstranica.repository.StudentRepositoryInterface defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.springstranica.entity.Student
```

I have looked some of the answers on stack and no solution for me. Pardon me if i skiped something. Can someone help and find where i did wrong and how can i prevent this from happening again.

The full code is available at [`github.com`](https://github.com/kraljevinaB/springstranica).

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- "*`... Not a managed type: class com.example.springstranica.entity.Student`*" - This class is missing an `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: @Turing85 no its not, but still thank you for trying

Comment: Does the code have an `@EntityScan(...)` annotation somehwere? if so: what is the value of this annotation?

Comment: It does, under @SpringBootApplication in main class, but it doesnt change anything, @EntityScan("com.example.springstranica"), it should have detected entity class already since its in package entity and has annotation.

Comment: You can take a look here https://github.com/kraljevinaB/springstranica

Comment: So I was correct after all. The `@Entity` annotation is missing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring-boot switched from JavaEE Persistence to JakartaEE Persistence from Release 3.0 onwards (`github.com`)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes).

When we look at the `pom.xml`, we see:

```
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

This imports the "old" JavaEE API, which is - as stated above - no longer supported by spring-boot and thus useless for us (but this is not directly the source of the exception).

Looking at `Student`'s imports, we see:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

So we use the "old" API in class `Student`, which is why spring reports that this entity is not managed (since the correct `@Entity` annotation is missing).

The solution is straightforward. We:

- remove `javax.persistence-api` from `pom.xml` (to prevent importing the wrong persistence api in the future), and
- replace `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistence` in `Student`.

This also makes the `@EntityScan` in class `SpringstranicaApplication` superfluous.